# How to update child class when parent class has changed?

Tags: c#, inheritance, parent-child

I'm having a little troubling figuring this out.

My code structure is as follows:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    private double p_num;

    public ParentClass()
    {
    }

    public void AddSomething(double num)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ParentNum + num);
    }

    public double ParentNum
    {
        set { p_num = value; }
        get { return p_num; }
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    private double c_num;

    public ChildClass()
    {

    }

    public void AddSomething()
    {
        base.AddSomething(ChildNum);
    }

    public double ChildNum
    {
        set { c_num = value; }
        get { return c_num; }
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ParentClass p = new ParentClass();
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.ChildNum = 8.0;
        p.ParentNum = 5.0;
        c.AddSomething();
    }
}
```

How comes this prints 8.0 and not 13.0?

Comment: If you want 13, add this line: "c.ParentNum = 5.0;" above "c.AddSomething();"

Comment: because `p` and `c` aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your Parent.p_num as static, it will work:

```
private static double p_num;
```

But i'm not sure if that is your intention. Do you mean to have p_num shared amogst all instances of the class?

By the way, you have a lot of unnecessary code in your classes. This will do:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public void AddSomething(double num) {
        System.Console.WriteLine(ParentNum + num);
    }

    public double ParentNum { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public void AddSomething() {
        base.AddSomething(ChildNum);
    }

    public double ChildNum { get; set; }
}
```

Reasons:

- No need to specify a default constructor.
- Use auto-properties instead of a backing field

Comment: Thanks Paul. Yes I want to have the parent information to be shared among all the children of the parent. Had a brainfart... Thanks for code cleanup, I'm new with C#

Comment: @ryrich - Are you saying that you will only ever have a single instance of the Parent class?

Answer (score 3):

Because `ChildClass` inherits from `ParentClass` does not mean that every instance of `ChildClass` inherits the properties of an instance of a `ParentClass`. They are separate objects.

To give a real-world analogy, were this true, if a mother got a scar, all her children would get the same scar.

Answer (score 2):

```
    ParentClass p = new ParentClass();
    ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
    c.ChildNum = 8.0;
    p.ParentNum = 5.0;
    c.AddSomething();
```

`p` and `c` has nothing in common here! They are just 2 separate objects.

Check this to get it more clear:

```
ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
c.ChildNum = 8.0;
c.ParentNum = 5.0;
c.AddSomething();
```

This will return 13.

Answer (score 1):

`p` and `c` are two different objects. When you call `c.AddSomething()`, the value of `c.ParentNum` is the default `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling `AddSomething` on your child class which is a completely separate instance to `ParentClass`. `ChildClass` is a subclass of `ParentClass`, but that doesn't mean they both point to the same `ParentClass`. You essentially have two objects and you are just calling an operation on 1 of them.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.ChildNum = 8.0;
        c.ParentNum = 5.0;
        c.AddSomething();
    }
}
```

Shall give you the result you desire